# Looking for Response Options in regards to an ASP.NET webforms App communicating with my MVC App

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms, restful-url

I have read a ton of questions/answers on here regarding questions similar or about topics this would cover.  I have come across a ton of different articles that outline setting up MVC to respond to inbound requests.

However, I have not been able to get a clear understanding of the limitations to the problem I am up against.

**Problem:**

I am creating an asp.net MVC 3 site.  However, there is two scenarios where I will have a asp.net WebForms application making calls into my site and I need to respond.

1. One is simply returning a couple strings
2. The second is a bit more complex, a query result, a undetermined amount of data for reporting purposes by the webforms app.

Because of #2, am I forced to use some type of service like SOAP so an object can be interchanged between both apps?

I really wanted to use a RESTful approach with my URI's but my shortcomings are

1. What limitations due to the reporting information I got to pass back
2. the response is going to a web-forms app

Can someone give me some insight on what my options are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need a separate service to deal with those specifics, I would start looking at Web API to meet those needs, you might even be able to leverage that API for other things

If Web API is too much of "early adoption" for you then you could fall back on WCF